# Greenplum Database

Tags: database, parallel-processing, enterprise, greenplum, data-lake

What are the major differences between Greenplum (GPDB) Community vs Enterprise Editions?

I want to get more details about the features which are available in enterprise edition as compared to community edition of Greenplum database.

Answer (score 1):

Let me clarify terms first.   The only two versions of Greenplum right now are:

- the Open Source version available via greenplum.org which is completely free.  This sometimes referred to as community edition but I prefer Open Source version - there used to be a "community edition" which was a VMware OVA file but that is long gone (was around the early Greenplum 4.X timeframe).
- VMware/Tanzu Greenplum available via the VMware download site.  This includes the database server and all other supporting products/utilities in the product (see below) as downloads.  It requires a customer number to login and use for download.  This typically requires a license fee as agreed upon after a product sale.  The Greenplum database server itself is the same as the open source version.

From the Greenplum release notes, these are the differences between the Open Source version and the licensed (enterprise) version:

**Differences Compared to Open Source Greenplum Database**

VMware Tanzu Greenplum 6.x includes all of the functionality in the open source Greenplum Database project and adds:

- Product packaging and installation script
- Support for QuickLZ compression. QuickLZ compression is not provided in the open source version of Greenplum Database due to licensing restrictions.
- Support for data connectors:
  Greenplum-Spark Connector
  Greenplum-Informatica Connector
  Greenplum-Kafka Integration
  Greenplum Streaming Server
- Data Direct ODBC/JDBC Drivers
- Greenplum PostGIS Extension
- gpcopy utility for copying or migrating objects between Greenplum systems
- Support for managing/monitoring Greenplum Database using VMware Tanzu Greenplum Command Center
- Support for full text search and text analysis using VMware Tanzu GPText
- Greenplum backup plugin for DD Boost
- Backup/restore storage plugin API

I hope this answers your question.

Jim